# Application / Activity instance leak

Tags: android, leakcanary

I need help in analysing the LeakCanary stacktrace. What exactly is leaking here and where?

**Desciption:** When app is launched an instance of com.myapp.Background.LifecycleMgmt.Application is called. In there all activity lifecycle events (onActivityCreated and onActivityDestroyed) are logged and stored. The activity com.myapp.Activities.Login seems to cause some problems here. As all activities are single instance I keep a reference to the activity in com.myapp.Background.LifecycleMgmt.Application, too.

```
16919874 bytes retained by leaking objects
Signature: d248be424a30809e9c4eb8c3aa1239b8aade385f
┬───
│ GC Root: System class
│
├─ com.google.android.gms.common.wrappers.InstantApps class
│    Leaking: NO (Application↓ is not leaking and a class is never leaking)
│    ↓ static InstantApps.zza
├─ com.myapp.Background.LifecycleMgmt.Application instance
│    Leaking: NO (Application is a singleton)
│    mBase instance of android.app.ContextImpl
│    ↓ Application.mLoadedApk
│                  ~~~~~~~~~~
├─ android.app.LoadedApk instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 16.9 MB in 75344 objects
│    mApplication instance of com.myapp.Background.LifecycleMgmt.Application
│    ↓ LoadedApk.mReceivers
│                ~~~~~~~~~~
├─ android.util.ArrayMap instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 16.9 MB in 75331 objects
│    ↓ ArrayMap.mArray
│               ~~~~~~
├─ java.lang.Object[] array
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 16.9 MB in 75329 objects
│    ↓ Object[].[4]
│               ~~~
╰→ com.myapp.Activities.Login instance
​     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because com.myapp.Activities.Login received
​     Activity#onDestroy() callback and Activity#mDestroyed is true)
​     Retaining 16.9 MB in 75251 objects
​     key = 84e153c7-7ba2-40df-9d20-dc51b28d4810
​     watchDurationMillis = 5901
​     retainedDurationMillis = 900
​     mApplication instance of com.myapp.Background.LifecycleMgmt.Application
​     mBase instance of androidx.appcompat.view.ContextThemeWrapper
```

Comment: Single instance Activity launch mode doesn't mean its a  singleton.

Comment: How das that relative to my question? Please clarify.

Comment: "As all activities are single instance I keep a reference to the activity in com.myapp.Background.LifecycleMgmt.Application, too." - so you keep hard references to Activity classes in your Application class?

Comment: I keep WeakReferences of them.

Comment: Ok - probably best to state that in the question then - with relevant code of how they are stored, along with Login activity code.